# Why state update not reflected on AndroidView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, I have an `AndroidView` with a listener that reads the state passed like this:

```
@Composable
fun Scanner(
    state: ScannerState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            ScannerView(context).apply {
                onButtonClicked = {
                    if (state.isLoading) <-- HERE I READ THE STATE   
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

The problem comes when the state is updated and the view recomposed. If the `onButtonClicked` callback is invoked again after that, it holds the initial state, and it's not reading the last updated state that this function received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`factory` is getting called only once, when the view is created. That's why the lambda captures only the initial state.

To pass the updated state, you need to use `update` argument, like this:

```
AndroidView(
    modifier = modifier,
    factory = { context ->
        ScannerView(context)
    },
    update = { view 
        view.onButtonClicked = {
            if (state.isLoading) {
                ...
            }
        }
    },
)
```